# Stopped from asking questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I posted some questions on main website of Ask Ubuntu and was rated -4.The reason was grammatical mistakes and lack of details (as per my views) so I was stopped from asking questions for three days. Again when I posted a question I was stopped  for two days, but the problem is that this time neither I have negative rating nor any grammatical mistakes. It would be really helpful to me someone could point out my mistakes.

Comment: A.B. you I did not understand what you did with "Again" and "but" while editing.Please try to clear.

Comment: He added a space before them. You omitted spaces in between of the full stops and these words.

Comment: @ByteCommander thanks,I really didn't noticed that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am a newbie

This is a completely superfluous statement and it doesn't entitle anyone to special treatment.

> The reason was grammatical mistakes and lack of details (as per my views)

Lack of details is probably correct, *"grammatical mistakes"* is absolutely not.

To earn reputation points and gain more [privileges](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges) users with low reputation are actually encouraged to proof read and improve things like spelling and formatting, which also teaches them that **most things can be fixed and improved** instead of ignored (locking up into your own filter bubble) or spewing hate.

> It would be really helpful to me if they also give me reasons to stopped from asking questions.

[That was exactly what I was trying to do.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/688363/how-to-install-wine#comment1004214_688363) Note that I was never banned from asking questions, so I don't have any personal experience how that situation is.

Your deleted question received a down vote from me because you simply pasted the command from an answer to another question without checking if you pasted and executed it correctly. You also didn't provide the error message in your question or the context (that you have been given this command by a user in another answer [link!], N.B. who was also a beginner). You have been carelessly posting across the board, ignoring every hint that the site gave you to solve your problem **efficiently**, like this for example when composing your question:

[image]

Contrary to the model of other sites on the web, this is not advertising, promotion or to just nag you. It's meant to help you, but you chose to ignore it. You say most of these are marked as duplicates? Correct! That means users around here took extra effort to look around if a similar question has been asked before and decide if there is an even better answer to this question. Remember: most things can be fixed and improved.

This is an ***efficient*** approach working towards getting better answers to *individual* questions. If you look at these and find that you still can't solve your problem reasonably quick, *then* you should ask a new question and provide enough details so that someone else has a chance to reproduce your particular issue and at least help to take it further. Otherwise you are wasting resources, like my time just now, or causing more confusion.

The way you did it, you wasted the time of the user answering your first question; the users who read, rated and commented on your second question; to then finally delete it, which probably didn't help to correct the negative balance caused by the amount of collected down votes but made it harder to retract votes for the other users.

There also is no *"THEY"*, the ban is implemented by an automatism.

> It seems that Ubuntu Community wants a quality research on the question before asking it.

No, you are still making false assumptions and are overgeneralizing. AskUbuntu is a site of the [StackExchange network (SE)](http://stackexchange.com/), meaning *some* Ubuntu users are active around here, but also other users from the network and even unregistered anonymous users.

Summary:

- You're not being harassed, especially not for grammatical mistakes, that's not a functional model of SE. If you experience harassment, report it.
- You're not supposed to do research for asking a question, but spend a reasonable amount of time and effort to compose a question that might solve a reproducible issue that someone else can solve.
- Questions and answers can be improved(, edited, rated, linked…). A question is not a filed/dead interaction/ticket hidden in your helpdesk's ticket system.
- Resources (people with enough knowledge who can actually answer your question and explain why instead of just pasting canned solutions with trial and error) are limited, therefore try to be as efficient as possible. It will benefit you too.

Comment: Thanks ,You provided me a lot of information like ban  is implemented by an automatism,but does adding that I am a newbie lets anyone to answer in detail and simple but not technical words.

Answer (score 7):

I think part of the problems you have are well... cause you don't quite get how stack exchange works. Have a look at the tour and the [help] pages.

While its a bit daunting, how to ask [questions](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) the smart way is a *great* resource on asking *better* questions and actually learning and researching more productively.

In essence, a good question is a *hard* or at least interesting question. It should also reflect your own research efforts.

Amusingly, I'm a low rep user on AU, and cannot see deleted posts. Of the ones I see here...

[How to install wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/688363/how-to-install-wine)

We don't know what the broken/held packages are. We don't know what unspeakable horrors you have inflicted on your system, or what needs to be done. While spamming error logs are bad, *essential* information helps others solve issues for you.

[Wine crashed on playonlinux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689869/wine-crashed-on-playonlinux)

Unclear what your problem is

It froze. We can't troubleshoot that for you. It would help to *wait* for a crash, or see if your processor or ram is overused or something. OP's answer is a *starting point* but it could be anything from a blotched install to solar flares.

https://askubuntu.com/a/690026/17681

Don't repeat answers, and post 'me too' answers. Post *substantial* answers that are *unique* and cover the problem in the question *specifically* - least at first. Eventually once you're familiar enough you COULD sneak in a clever one liner.

Comment: It seems that Ubuntu Community wants a quality research on the question before asking it.And would try to do so.

Comment: @Journeyman *How To Ask Questions The Smart Way* recommends StackOverflow/StackExchange, but the following should also be noted: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1796/237803 :)

Comment: "The irony of the thing that Eric Raymond wrote is that the type of people that ask bad questions are not going to read this giant "Treatise on how to ask questions." If I get someone to read it, its a victory, no? ;p

Comment: That depends on how the knowledge is used or if at all. ;P